# Self-contained vrs Framework-Dependent Deployment

Tags: asp.net-core

I was deploying an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application to my site, and I found out that my host only supports "Self-contained x86" applications.

Is there a difference in performance between Framework-Dependent x64 Deployment and Self-contained? There must be memory performance in x86 vrs x64 versions.

If I am using self-contained, what issues do I have to consider in my programming?: Memory problems? Disc space? connections? Speed or other undocumented problems. ie. x64 vrs x86 deployment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Framework dependent:**
The server has DotNetCore framework libraries installed, you only deploy your own code and third party codes other than the framework.

**Self-contained:**
You deploy all the code required to run your application including the framework. The server doesn't have to have the framework installed

for more details read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

**[EDIT]**

The memory consumption for the framework is not that much, if you just debug any simple web application using VS2019 or earlier you will see ~70MB of memory usage, and considering that even shared host services are allocating at least 128MB of instant memory it will be enough to run a simple app.

But you can't determine your minimum requirements with reference to the framework only. You should consider many things like;

- how large is your project
- how much resources and external libraries are in use
- how many instant visitors you are expecting
- and how efficient is your code...

Comment: I was asking about speed or other undocumented problems. ie. x64 vrs x86 deployment.

Comment: In self-contained deployment you will need a few more megabytes for disc space and memory because you will be deploying the framework as well. But the major factors of speed and other issues is the server setup and your own code.

Comment: So if theres a need for more resources with Self-contained, what would minimum requirements (RAM) for asp net core  Self-contained be on the server?

Comment: well, I added more details to the answer